# How to build apk of Webview in flutter

Tags: java, flutter, android-studio, devise, stack-overflow

How we build apk of web view app in a flutter. Does anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

For build an APK you use:

```
flutter build apk .
```

For build a bundle:

```
flutter build appbundle
```

For build apk and split by arch

```
flutter build apk --split-per-abi
```

These is the modes that can you build for Android in flutter.

The webView is a feature of your application, so don't have a different type of build .

Check this doc:
https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android

Answer (score 0):

```
flutter build apk
```

This typically build for debug mode. For more specific result, use ~

```
flutter build apk --release
```

or,

```
flutter build apk --debug
```